Getting paid back for tzedakah, from rosh Hashanah?
B"H
Razal say that giving tzedakah is only taking a loan from Hashem that He will pay back, and that one can benefit from the mitzvah of tzedakah even in this world, and Hashem will pay you back double.
But it also says that all the money one is destined to make is decided on rosh Hashanah, and one's job etc is only to be able to receive that money physically.
Is getting paid back double from giving tzedakah considered part of one's job that one uses to collect the money decided on rosh Hashanah, or is getting paid back double for giving tzedakah not at all part of the calculation of how much money one is supposed to have that year, similar to how however much money one spends on shabbbos one will be paid back, and it's not part of the calculation?

What's the nafka mina?

@RabbiKaii the nafka mina is if you mikadeish an isha on the condition that the explanation is one way or another, is she mikudeshes?

@RabbiKaii you can also ask what's the nafka mina knowing that all the money you spend on shabbbos will be paid back because it's pre determined or not.. the main difference is that if it's not pre determined and one will get paid double then one can just keep giving an infinite amount and keep getting infinite money, but if it's pre determined maybe one should only give a little bit at a time and not so much

I read your great comment about mikadeish isha while shopping in the supermarket and it was so funny I laughed out loud. Thanks for that :) Note: I've asked similar and I am still wanting to know a nafka mina so if you have an answer here's my question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132460/what-ways-does-hashem-pay-you-back-for-money-spent-on-shabbat-torah-etc
